# makefile question

Tags: makefile

I'm looking to modify a makefile to include a local directory of headers. However, most of the makefile compilation happens outside my current makefile limiting what I can do. Here's the current makefile:

```
TARGET =    final    
LIBS =      -lsimple -lcheck -lsuif -luseful    
OBJS =      doproc.o main.o

all:            $(TARGET)

install-bin:    install-prog
include $(SUIFHOME)/Makefile.std
```

The directory of headers (boost) I wish to use of is in the same directory as this makefile and doproc.cc/main.cc. I tried modifying the makefile to this

```
TARGET =    final
INC=        -I/boost
LIBS =      -lsimple -lcheck -lsuif -luseful
OBJS =      doproc.o main.o

all:            $(TARGET) $(INC)

install-bin:    install-prog

include $(SUIFHOME)/Makefile.std
```

but to no effect. I have an account on this machine but no root access and I can't change Makefile.std. If this is trivial, I apologize. I'm not used to using makefiles.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:

The suggestions so far are helpful for getting me the right directory. But It's still not making the directory be included in the compilation

Comment: C++ and makefiles are unrelated.

Comment: @user127817: what are you trying to achieve by `all: $(TARGET) $(INC)`? Making it dependent on `all` may make some sense under some circumstances, but you're giving a folder as dependency - what do you expect?

Comment: @user127817: just a guess, wouldn't appending the (corrected) `$(INC)` have to go in `CXXFLAGS` (or `CFLAGS`)? Or does `Makefile.std` somehow consume that variable?

Comment: 1) How big is Makefile.std, 2) can you make a local copy of it, just for debugging purposes, and 3) can you show us the rule that compiles things?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, it's really hard to discern all details without knowing the internals of `Makefile.std`. However, let's assume that `$(INC)` is not somehow magically consumed inside Makefile.std (it's at least not one of the default macros, see `make -p` for those), in this case you would have to append your include folders to `CXXFLAGS` (for C++) or `CFLAGS` (for C) like so:

```
CXXFLAGS+=$(CXXFLAGS) -I$(MAKEDIR)/boost
```

Side-note: There are variations on this, but from where I stand

```
all:            $(TARGET) $(INC)
```

doesn't make too much sense for a value of `-I/boost` or even the corrected `-I$(MAKEDIR)/boost`. The reason is that it is no variable assignment (which is possible instead of dependencies) and thus would be considered as a file dependency (unless declared `.PHONY`).

I should add that I'm assuming the usual default rules that come with GNU make. Otherwise you'd have to show us the actual rules `%.o: %.cpp` etc ...

Answer (score 1):

Use this - Your current INC specifies /boost not ./boost:

```
INC=        -I$(PWD)/boost
```

Comment: Actually `$(MAKEDIR)` should be the smarter choice, given the description of where the make file seems to be located.

Comment: @STATUS: Yep, makes sense, post an answer!

Comment: okay, did that. It's just too many unknowns from the question for my taste, so I was unsure whether to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the leading `/` in front of boost. You're telling the compiler to look in `/boost` under the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

`/` is filesystem root; `./` is current directory.

Did you mean `-I./boost`? `-Iboost` works too.